# Set colors for individual points in altair

Tags: python, altair

Given a DataFrame `data` of point coordinates `'x'`, `'y'` and hex string colors (e.g. `'#ab1234'`), how do I set the color of each point using the `'color'` column? I have tried the following but in both cases the colors appear random:

```
from altair import Chart

points = Chart(data).mark_point().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y:Q'
).encode(color='color')

points = Chart(data).mark_point().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y:Q',
    color='color'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`color=alt.Color('color:N', scale=None)` should work.

Comment: Thank you - still getting used to the syntax!